# I'm unable to find a rigorous proof for the following problem. I've been stuck and don't know how to approach this problem.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence, summation

Let $(a_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$  be a sequence such that $\liminf |a_n| = 0$. Prove there is
a subsequence $ (a_{n_k})_{k \in \mathbb{N}} $ such that $\sum_{k = 1}^{\infty}(a_{n_k})$ converges.

Comment: Use the property for lower limits. Since $\liminf|a_n|=0$, for every $c>0$ and every $n\in\mathbb{N}$, there exists some $N>n$ such that $|a_N|<c$.

Comment: Thanks @BernardPan

Comment: Can you elaborate your answer @BernardPan

Comment: $\lim\inf |a_n|$ is just the least accumulation point of $|a_n|$, $c$ is a positive real number, and so is $|a_n|$. You can always find a term in your sequence with an absolute value less than $c$ for a sufficiently large $n$- you can do that infinitely many times. It is necessary that $|a_{n_k}|$ converges. You should be able to find a convergent subsequence s.t. the given series converges. For an illustration, many of the geometric series are subseries of the harmonic series.

Answer (score 1):

We first set $n_0=1$ and $c_1=1$. By the property of $\liminf$, there exists $n_1>n_0=1$ such that $|a_{n_1}|<c_1=1$.

Then we set $c_2=1/4$. Again, there exists $n_2>n_1$ such that $|a_{n_2}|<c_2=1/4$.

We can continue this fashion. At the $k$-th step, we set $c_k=1/k^2$ and we can then find some $n_k>n_{k-1}$ such that $|a_{n_k}|<c_k=1/k^2$.

Note that 
$$\sum_{k=1}^\infty{|a_{n_k}|}<\sum_{k=1}^\infty{\frac{1}{k^2}}.$$

Since the RHS converges, the LHS converges, i.e., $\sum_{k=1}^\infty{a_{n_k}}$ converges absolutely.

Comment: Thanks again@BernardPan